# How to copy files matching pattern to subdirectory with pattern in name

Tags: linux, find, cp

I have following directory structure:

```
folder-1.2.3/subA/subB/file.txt
folder-1.2.3/subA/subB/other_sub/file2.txt
folder-1.2.4/subA/subB/file.txt
folder-1.2.4/subA/subB/other_sub/file2.txt
```

I want to match all paths starting with `folder-*/subA/subB` and copy its content to `/new_dst/prefix-*` where `*` is matched string (1.2.3 or 1.2.4 in my case).
The outcome would be:

```
new_dst/prefix-1.2.3/file.txt
new_dst/prefix-1.2.3/other_sub/file2.txt
new_dst/prefix-1.2.4/file.txt
new_dst/prefix-1.2.4/other_sub/file2.txt
```

I can use any standard linux command (cp, find, grep, aws, sed..). My initial idea was to use find (`find . -path "folder-*/subA/subB"`) but I don't have direct access what pattern was matched only the whole path. That's why I tried to parse it through sed (for example `.. -exec sed -i "s/folder-//g"`) but it's starting to look more complicated than it should be.

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting first to locate the desired files using `find` command and `-path` option.

```
 find root-folder -path "*/subA/subB/*" -name "*.txt"
```

Once your files are located. Feed the found files into `cp` command.

```
 cp $(find root-folder -path "*/subA/subB/*" -name "*.txt") target-folder
```